# Troubles with Embarcadero XE6 - Delphi XE6 developing apps

Tags: android, windows, delphi, batch-file, delphi-xe6

I have the Embarcadero XE6, but use only the Delphi XE6.
When I run my app Delphi project, it compiles correctly, but when Delphi attempts to install this app directly on the device SDK ADV or a physical device, the following error occurs:

> Unable to create process: Unable to install ''. Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_INCONSISTENT_CERTIFICATES]

So I created a batch file, so that my app stay certificate, and only this way can
manually install on mobile device.

The batch file contains:

```
cd\
D:
cd Program Files
cd Java
cd jdk1.7.0_25
cd bin
jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore my-release-key.keystore -storepass android D:\DelphiPrograms\App01\Android\Debug\MyApp\bin\MyApp.apk androiddebugkey
cd\
D:
cd Users
cd Public
cd Documents
cd Embarcadero
cd Studio
cd 14.0
cd PlatformSDKs
cd adt-bundle-windows-x86-20131030
cd sdk
cd platform-tools
adb -s emulator-5554 install -r D:\DelphiPrograms\App01\Android\Debug\MyApp\bin\MyApp.apk
pause
```

But whenever change the app, I have to run this batch file, and I see that dont need nothing of this. Delphi automatically installs the app into device.

Note: when I installed Embarcadero XE6, ZipAlign.exe the file did not exit, and zipalign.bat was empty, so I copied the ZipAlign.exe from internet, and also copied the batch file commands from the internet.

My file ZipAllign.bat contains the following command lines:

```
@echo off
REM Batch file to recursively zip align *.apk files in a directory
REM and its sub-directories. This is significantly easier and faster
REM than manually zip aligning them.
@echo Zip aligning now...
for /R %%X in (*.apk) do zipalign 4 "%%X" "%%~dpX%%~nX.new"
@echo Replacing non-aligned files with zip aligned files...
for /R %%X in (*.new) do move /Y "%%X" "%%~dpX%%~nX.apk"
@echo Zip aligning done, press any key to exit
pause
```

But the error keeps, and can not run the app in Delphi for the SDK device directly, without having to run the batch file I created for my app to be certified.

Does ZipAllign.bat file is complete or missing some command lines?

Answer (score 0):

Click Run|Parameters...

Put `-cleaninstall` in the Parameters box.

If you have an old version of the APK (from say XE5) on the device then uninstall it.

If you are compiling a Release version make sure you have a certificate defined in Project|Options...|Provisioning.

Answer (score 0):

This problem could happen if a keystore file was copied from another machine.  If this was the case,  try uninstall the apk first,  or recreate the keystore file on the new machine.